# How to pass "--external-locking" for mysqld in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I would like to start my mysql server with the `--external-locking` option. As  mysqld is run by the /etc/init.d/mysql script ubuntu (karmic), I guess that's where I should set this "--external-locking" thing, just can't figure out where to put it(am far from expertise in shell scripting:). Could anyone please help me with that?

Setting variable in /etc/mysql/my.cnf would be probably an easier option, but either I'm being bitten by [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41769) or I just don't define it correctly, but with all of the given parameters:

```
a) external-locking = on
b) external-locking = off
c) #skip-external-locking
d) skip-external-locking
```

being set in my.cnf the output of `mysql> show variables like '%locking%';`
is the same:

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| skip_external_locking | ON    | 
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm hoping that --external-locking passed to mysqld would do the trick, just can't find out how to set this url parameter in /etc/init.d/mysql startup (shell) script.

thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. Mysql version 5.1.37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

external-locking is the correct answer. put the string in the [mysqld] section of the config file. (if still not working might be that bug is responsible...)

Comment: Yayy! indeed the "external-locking" (without any =off, or =on) was the right setting for the my.cnf. Thanks a lot!